# Python dictionary not storing all the rows in form of key value pair

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

Newbie in python. In Below code I am fetching 4610 rows from `DB` and storing them in dictionary pattern. It is extracting all the rows till the second last line of code and `normalize()` the decimal values but when I am printing the `len(SDIValues)` it is only 146. It should be 4600.

```
#len(SDIData) = 4610rows fetched from MySQL DB

for data in SDIData:  
  Ibesticker =data[1].strip()
  key = (data[0],Ibesticker)
  if(data[3] != None):
    PeriodYear = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[3], "%Y-%m-%d")
    val = float(data[10].normalize())
    print val  #returns 4600 values
    SDIValues[key] = [PeriodYear.year, val, PeriodYear.month]   # something is wrong here i guess

print len(SDIValues) # 146 rows
```

Comment: This is likely because of duplicate keys.

Comment: Yeah may be..did not crossed my mind. thanks a lot